# MomentJS, how to ignore user's local timezone, and use

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

Here's the scenario:

1- User opens the website, and enters 07:00 am using a dropdown field, which will give me this :

// 1578600000000 => Save to DB
// Fri Jan 10 2020 07:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

The user himself is in **Sydney**, which means his local clock is on `GMT+1100`

However, he wants to represent this time as Asia/Tehran time, because that's where he's going to be tomorrow. So essentially, **he wants me to completely ignore his local time** and see him as if he's in Asia/Tehran. So when he's in `Tehran` tomorrow, he can see his calendar has `07:00am`.

On the other hand, are the people all over the world who will see his available time, let's say from `Australia/Perth`.

I thought something like the below work, as per `momentJS` documentation, but it doesn't.

First, convert the timezone to `Asia/Tehran`, which is the user's desired place:

```
const desiredTimeZone = 'Asia/Tehran';
let OriginalDesired = moment.tz(1578600000000,desiredTimeZone);
```

Then, when representing it to the people in `Australia/Perth` make sure it's in their timezone

```
const PerthTimeZone = 'Australia/Perth`; // this is dynamic, can be anything

OriginalDesired.clone().tz(PerthTimeZone);
```

I naively thought this should work. But I noticed the original timestamp `1578600000000` is a `UTC` timestamp, meaning it's not really `07:00am`, it's actually `20:00pm`, because Javascript
has subtracted `11` hours, which is the very original user's local timezone's offset, from the user entry.

I managed to work around it by adding and subtracting the offset in a dramatic way, but it only works in one scenario.

```
const originalTime = 1578600000000;
const LocalAdjustment = moment(originalTime).tz("Australia/Sydney").utcOffset() * 60000;

const DesiredAdjustment = moment(originalTime).tz("Asia/Tehran").utcOffset() * 60000;
const newUTC = originalTime + LocalAdjustment - DesiredAdjustment;
```

And when representing this to the user's in `Tehran`

```
  moment(newUTC).tz("Asia/Tehran").format('hh:mma'); // 07:00am.
```

**I know this is probably stupid and obviously only works in one scenario, but is this the right path that I'm going? or is there an easier way?**

By the way, all the calculations are on my server, which is 'UTC'.

Comment: Is the value from the first example stored in your database as 1578600000000 or as 1578600000000 + 11 hours? momentjs stores and operates on UTC and you want to store an _offset from current UTC time_. Try using `OriginalDesired.utcOffset(yourTzOffset, true)` to change the internal UTC representation to match your desired timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> 1- User opens the website, and enters 07:00 am using a dropdown field, which will give me this :  // 1578600000000 ...

You've already lost.  If the local time zone is not relevant, then don't write code that assumes that it is.

In other words, you probably have something along the lines of:

```
moment("2020-01-10 07:00")
```

Instead you should have something like:

```
moment.tz("2020-01-10 07:00", "Asia/Tehran")
```

Or rather, you should simply send `"2020-01-10 07:00"` and `"Asia/Tehran"` to your database, then later retrieve them and pass them to moment-timezone when you need to know what moment that represents.

As to your other approach, it's generally not a good idea to add or subtract time zone offsets from timestamps.  Unix timestamps are inherently UTC based.  Adding or subtracting will produce a different moment in time, not adjust for time zone.

Consider that there's also a slim (but not impossible) chance that the offsets returned by your code are incorrect, as they would have to be shifted before being looked up. In other words, Tehran was at UTC+3:30 on the date in question, so the timestamp passed would have to be adjusted by 3 hours 3 minutes *before* being passed to the moment constructor.  This leads to circular logic, and is difficult to resolve.  It will show up for timestamps near transitions (either for DST, or for changes to standard time for a particular time zone).

Comment: thank you so much, I managed to make this work without moving the entire code base from timestamp to other options.
Unfortunately, I had decided to use date-fns for the UI code which appeared to be way nicer at first, in comparison to Moment.js, however, when it comes to timeZones, date-fns is far away from being a reliable option.
The way MomentJS handles timzone conversion is just way easier and more reliable.
Thanks again

Comment: on a side note, I now save the actualy date as strings, along with the timestamps in my DB and I always adjust them based on the current user's timeZone on the fly, when a query is being made to my DB.
While I'll be reading more and more to understand, do you think there's an issue with this? 
Is DTS  going to be a problem soon?

Comment: Which DB?  Most have proper date and time types.  Avoid storing as strings.  Also, moment is in maintenance mode.  You might try [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)